# Calculations on webpage using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some code that people on here have kindly helped me with, I need to make a slight amendment but I am struggling to get it to work. I have added the code to a jsfiddle

I would like another two boxes to add number of payments and cost of premium. (I have labelled them "2)

You will see the first two boxes calculate the sub total (the total including redress works on my webpage but for some reason doesn't on the fiddle)

Can you help please?

http://jsfiddle.net/arrNe/1/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var sum = 0;
    function calcSum(prevVal) {
        var val1 = $('#val1').val();
        var val2 = $('#val2').val();
        sum = parseFloat(val1) * parseFloat(val2);
        return sum;
    }
    var subAmt = $("#sub"),
        taxAmt = $("#tax"),
        totAmt = $("#total");
    $(".val").each(function () {
        var prevVal = this.value / 1,
            self = this;

        $(this).keyup(function () {
            subAmt.val(calcSum.call(self, prevVal));
            totAmt.val(sum + sum * parseFloat(taxAmt.val() / 100));
            prevVal = self.value;

        });
    });
});
```

Comment: please specify what you actually want

Comment: I would like to have two calculations (number of payments * cost of premium)

Comment: could you tell us what you don't understand or what it is you want to happen that is not happening?

Comment: `taxAmt = $("#tax"),` There is nothing with id `tax`.

Comment: Also, ids should be unique. You've assigned `val1` and `val2` to more than one entity.

Comment: i mean what should be the output, i can see only the text fields in your fiddle

Comment: Sorry if I am not explaining this propely.

Comment: I would like the page to have two caluclations
So for example 4*5 in the first two boxes
10*5 in the second two boxes 
Then the subtotal would equal 70 (20+50)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per what i have understood by your last comment.

You should have different ids for third and fourth box i.e. `#val3 , #val4` respectively.

So it would be somewhat like this. 
See this updated **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/arrNe/2/)** of yours.

Entering the value 4,5,10,5 respectively in the 4 boxes, your subtotal would be 70 as expected.

`Just a note`: call the function `calcSum` only when all the four fields are provided. Put the conditions over there otherwise it would return NaN(not a number) even if one field is missing.

```
if(val1 && val2 && val3 && val4){
    // do your calculation and return the sum
}
else{
    alert("please fill all the fields :)");
}
```

Comment: Hi Varun, this is perfect.Thank you very much for your help.I am happy for the NaN if the second numbers are left as 0. In fact I wil put default as 0 in the second numbers,.

Comment: Thanks again and sorry if I wasn't very cleasr

Comment: It's ok @padders01. Glad to help :)